# How to change interface font in firefox android version (Fennec )?

Tags: fennec, tamil

I tried viewing a website in tamil characters (eg. http://ta.wiktionary.org) using firefox mobile version in my android phone (android version 2.3.3). I find all the text as boxes. This is because android 2.3.3 doesnt come with tamil fonts.

I like to know if we have an option in fennec to choose a custom font(which supports tamil support) to show website text.

Answer (score 0):

To view Tamil Fonts in android phone without installing any fonts in the android USE
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/tamil-fonts-package/